# How to fix this simple MySQL display order issue

Tags: php, mysql

I'm very new to MySQL so I need some help please,

I have a table called "posts", this table has the following columns:

**id** - this is auto increment and primary key
**title**
**content**

I have a PHP page where I want to display all the posts from the database table. I want the title to show first and then the post content followed by the title of the next post and it's post content and so on... However if I do this:

```
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC");

while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($select))
{
   echo $result['title'] . "<br />";
   echo $result['content'];
}
```

Of course I get a list of all my post titles followed by all my post contents. In other words it's like this:

> ```
> DogsCats
>
> Are also known as canines.Are also known as felines.
>
> Instead of:
>
> Dogs
>
> Are also known as canines
>
> Cats
>
> Are also known as felines
> ```

What would I need to do to fix this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($select))
{
   echo $result['title'] . "<br />";
   echo $result['content'] . "<br /><br />";
}
```

You're missing a line break after your content, so first occurrence would be fine, but it'll merge first content with second title.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following for your loop:

```
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($select))
{
   echo $result['title'] . "<br />" . $result['content'] . "<br />";
}
```

Alternatively:

```
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($select))
{
   printf("%s <br /> %s <br />", $result['title'], $result['content']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should tell PHP what kind of array you want (`MYSQL_ASSOC, MYSQL_NUM, MYSQL_BOTH`).

Since you are using column names as array subscripts, you should use `MYSQL_ASSOC` or `MYSQL_BOTH`:

```
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($select, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    ...
```